# Detect specific line from output of python-vlc from console while playing video in python pyqt5

Tags: python, pyqt5, ctypes, vlc, python-vlc

when i am trying to play a video with python-vlc in pyqt5 like

```
import vlc,sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
app = QApplication([])
window = QWidget()
window.resize(500,500)
window.show()
instance=vlc.Instance()
p=instance.media_player_new()
p.set_hwnd(window.winId())
p.set_media(instance.media_new(path_to_media))
p.play()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

It prints lot of errors in console like

```
[032ac2b0] direct3d11 vout display error: Direct3D11 could not be opened
[032ac2b0] direct3d11 vout display error: SetThumbNailClip failed: 0x800706f4
[0325de20] d3d11va generic error: D3D11CreateDevice failed. (hr=0x80004001)
[0325de20] d3d11va generic error: Failed to create device
[032ac2b0] direct3d9 vout display error: SetThumbNailClip failed: 0x800706f4
[032ad4f8] direct3d11 vout display error: Could not Create the D3D11 device. (hr=0x80004001)
[032ad4f8] direct3d11 vout display error: Direct3D11 could not be opened
[032ad4f8] direct3d11 vout display error: SetThumbNailClip failed: 0x800706f4
[0325e3c0] dxva2 generic error: FindVideoServiceConversion failed
[032ad4f8] direct3d9 vout display error: SetThumbNailClip failed: 0x800706f4
[032acee0] direct3d11 vout display error: Could not Create the D3D11 device. (hr=0x80004001)
[032acee0] direct3d11 vout display error: Direct3D11 could not be opened
[032acee0] direct3d11 vout display error: SetThumbNailClip failed: 0x800706f4
```

I want to capture one line from all those printed error.and that process has to run all time.cause i dont know when the error line will print.
Is there any way ,that i can detect detect?

**Edit For Review**

I have successfully implemented what discussed in that forum and got the result after little bit modification.Here is the code

```
import vlc,sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import ctypes


# Prepare `vsnprintf` function
if sys.platform.startswith('win'):
    # Note: must use same version of libc as libvlc
    vsnprintf = ctypes.cdll.msvcrt.vsnprintf
else:
    libc = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(ctypes.util.find_library('c'))
    vsnprintf = libc.vsnprintf

vsnprintf.restype = ctypes.c_int
vsnprintf.argtypes = (
    ctypes.c_char_p,
    ctypes.c_size_t,
    ctypes.c_char_p,
    ctypes.c_void_p,
)

# Your callback here
@vlc.CallbackDecorators.LogCb
def log_callback(data, level, ctx, fmt, args):
    # Skip if level is lower than warning
    if level < 3:
        return

    # Format given fmt/args pair
    BUF_LEN = 1024
    outBuf = ctypes.create_string_buffer(BUF_LEN)
    vsnprintf(outBuf, BUF_LEN, fmt, args)
    
    # Print it out, or do something else
    print('LOG: ' + outBuf.raw.replace(b"\x00",b"").decode())

# Set callback to the libvlc instance

app = QApplication([])
window = QWidget()
window.resize(500,500)
window.show()
instance=vlc.Instance()
instance.log_set(log_callback, None)
p=instance.media_player_new()
p.set_hwnd(window.winId())
p.set_media(instance.media_new(r"D:\Y2Mate.is - Starla Edney - Queen of Hearts (by Monoir) [Official Video]-o7c5LxzmZvs-480p-1636735291163.mp4"))
p.play()

sys.exit(app.exec_()) 

----OUTPUT-----
LOG: buffer too late (-95361 us): dropped
LOG: buffer too late (-73141 us): dropped
LOG: playback too late (74687): up-sampling
LOG: unsupported control query 3
```

**But** the problem arises when i use this inside a class because I want to use a pyqtsignal.

```
import vlc,sys,ctypes
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *

class logPrinter(QObject):
    logerror=pyqtSignal() # I want to use a pyqtsignal after getting a specified error ,so i use Class
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
    @vlc.CallbackDecorators.LogCb
    def log_callback(self,data, level, ctx, fmt, args):
    # Skip if level is lower than warning
        if level < 3:
            return
        # Format given fmt/args pair
        BUF_LEN = 1024
        outBuf = ctypes.create_string_buffer(BUF_LEN)
        vsnprintf(outBuf, BUF_LEN, fmt, args)
        
        # Print it out, or do something else
        print('LOG: ' + outBuf.raw.replace(b"\x00",b"").decode())

    # Set callback to the libvlc instance
class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.resize(500,500)
        instance=vlc.Instance()
        self.log_printer=logPrinter()
        instance.log_set(self.log_printer.log_callback, None)
        p=instance.media_player_new()
        p.set_hwnd(self.winId())
        p.set_media(instance.media_new(path_to_media))
        p.play()
app = QApplication([])
window = Window()
window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Video is playing but it generating error continuously

```
Exception ignored on calling ctypes callback function: <function logPrinter.log_callback at 0x02B7BCD0>
TypeError: log_callback() missing 1 required positional argument: 'args'
Exception ignored on calling ctypes callback function: <function logPrinter.log_callback at 0x02B7BCD0>
TypeError: log_callback() missing 1 required positional argument: 'args'
Exception ignored on calling ctypes callback function: <function logPrinter.log_callback at 0x02B7BCD0>
TypeError: log_callback() missing 1 required positional argument: 'args'
```

I think using that **log_callback()** inside class causing error for mismatch in method arguments/parameters.

Comment: Python is very friendly language, just open vlc module from site-packages and analyze how and where it prints errors, all you need to know is little bit of ctypes and common programming, and I think you know it already, since you're a hacker.

Comment: I checked but there is nothing. I think its coming from that libvlc.dll. Cause vlc module is not a concrete module its a wrapper only..So is there any other way to trace it from console...?

Comment: try libvlc_log_set

Comment: See this https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?f=32&t=131018

Comment: thank u @musicamante ,@mugiseyebrows ,but there is a problem after implementing in class.I posted the error for your better understanding in my Original post. I will remove that after u got the point properly.

Comment: @Hacker6914 no need to remove that, it's still consistent with the question. From what I can understand, it seems that the decorators is unable to call the function as an instance method. Unfortunately I don't have that much knowledge on the way ctype decorators work, and I cannot do any testing on the vlc module right now.

Comment: Why not leaving *log\_callback* outside any class and simply call it from methods?

Comment: No I want to use pyqtsignal for a specific error/log. I think if we can not use that method inside a class then leave that to outside, and make a class for pyqtsignal and declare that class object as global object so that we can use from outside that means from log_callback. if there is any better way let me know...